# Add results of 2 queries into a single list and then sort it

Tags: c#, list, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

In my model I have 2 classes: `ParticipantCompany` and `ParticipantPerson` who both inherit from `Participant` and have string property `.Name`. They also both realise `IParticipant` that requires them to have `.Name`

```
public interface IParticipant 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ParticipantCompany : Participant, IParticipant
{
    public ParticipantCompany():this(false, "","","","") { }
    public ParticipantCompany (bool isclient) : this(isclient, "","","","") { }
    public ParticipantCompany(bool isclient, string name, string address, string inncompany, string ogrn) : base(isclient, SubjectType.Company)
    {
        Name = name;
        Address = address;
        InnCompany = inncompany;
        Ogrn = ogrn;
    }
    public string InnCompany { get; set; }
    public string Ogrn { get; set; }
}
public class ParticipantPerson : Participant, IParticipant
{
    public ParticipantPerson() : this(false,"","","","") { }
    public ParticipantPerson(bool isclient) : this(isclient, "", "", "", "") { }
    public ParticipantPerson(bool isclient, string name, string address, string innperson, string ogrnip) : base(isclient, SubjectType.Person) 
    {
        Name = name;
        Address = address;
        InnPerson = innperson;
        Ogrnip = ogrnip;
    }
public string InnPerson { get; set; }
    public string Ogrnip { get; set; }
}
public abstract class Participant
{
    public Participant(bool isclient, SubjectType Type,  string name, string address) 
    { 
        SubjType = Type;
        IsClient = isclient;
        Name = name;
        Address = address;
    }

    public Participant(bool isclient, SubjectType Type ) : this(isclient, Type, "","")
    {

    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public  SubjectType SubjType { get; private set; }
    public bool IsClient { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public List<LegalCase> Cases { get; set; } = new List<LegalCase>();

}
```

Here's the model itself:

```
class CaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ParticipantCompany> Companies{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<ParticipantPerson> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LegalCase> Cases { get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        => options.UseSqlite("Data Source=Clients.db");
```

}

What I want to do is query for all `Company`s and all `Person`s, merge the results into a single list and then sort the list by `.Name`.

```
        using(var db = new CaseContext())
        {
            var companies = db.Companies.ToList();
            var persons = db.Persons.ToList();
            //Cant convert from System.Collections.
            //Generic.List<Magna.CaseModel.ParticipantPerson> to 
            //System.Colleciton.Generic.IEnumerable<Magna.CaseModel.ParticipantCompany>
            List<IParticipant> participants = companies.AddRange(persons);

        }
```

Comment: You won't be able to do this without some casting as the types are just different. Perhaps something like `companies.Cast<IParticipant>().Concat(persons.Cast<IParticipant>()).OrderBy(x => x.Name)`? However, notice that you lose the types, and you're left with `IParticipant`, but you don't mention whether this is acceptable or not

Comment: I want the Companies and Persons to mix together as far as user interface is concerned (like placing their names on a single ListBox) I don't think actually putting them into a single list is a hard requirement, would you advice against it? I could make a `List<string>` of names if needed.

Comment: If that `participants` would be returned by say, JSON, then my comment above might be what you're looking for, but UI is an extremely broad term

Comment: You want to put all companies and persons into a list of *what*? They are two different things. They could be cast to a `Participant` or an `IParticpant`. The end result that you're looking for is not clear.

Comment: I mean editing database-provided data in GUI created with WPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can merge all companies and persons into a single list as follows:

```
//store actual data in below two variables
List<ParticipantPerson> participantPersons = new List<ParticipantPerson>();
List<ParticipantCompany> participantCompanies = new List<ParticipantCompany>();

//Merge them using Linq and anonymous types
var mergedList = participantPersons.Select(pp => new { Id = pp.Id, SubjType = pp.SubjType, IsClient = pp.IsClient, Name = pp.Name, Address = pp.Address,  InnPerson = pp.InnPerson, Ogrnip = pp.Ogrnip, InnCompany = (string)null, Ogrn = (string)null }).ToList();
mergedList.AddRange(participantCompanies.Select(pc => new {Id = pc.Id, SubjType = pc.SubjType, IsClient = pc.IsClient, Name = pc.Name, Address = pc.Address, InnPerson = (string) null, Ogrnip = (string) null, InnCompany = pc.InnCompany, Ogrn = pc.Ogrn}));
```

Or we can also create a new class with all the above properties of anonymous type and use the object of that class instead of anonymous type in Select query.